# Untar tar.gz file using perl

Tags: xml, perl, tar

I have a tar.gz file which has a HUGE XML inside it .. I need to extract the file using Archive::tar in perl ... I'm using the below code which is only extracting the zipped XML file from tar.gz file .. but i need to extract the XML as well in one step ...
I'm using the below code ...

```
 TAR__PATH= 'C:\\Perl\IN\Work\tar_file_20130426.xml.tar
 my $extract_obj = Archive::Extract->new(archive => $TAR_FILE_WORK_PATH, type => 'tar');
```

Comment: Hmm.. you want to "use" `Archive::Tar` but your code snippet uses `Archive::Extract`.

Comment: Your code snippet is not valid perl.

Comment: Did you mean you extracted tarred XML file? Having a zipped XML file inside tar.gz is something else and is pretty unusual. It should be also possible to read the file without extracting it first. Do you need to read a file in `tar.gz` or you need to have it on disk? Edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code;

```
use Archive::Tar;

my $tar=Archive::Tar->new();

$tar->read('/path/of/tar/test.tar.gz');
$tar->extract();
```

It will extract the content in current path. Hope, it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the update .. I was using Archive::Tar but since I am trying to unzip a tar.gz file which is huge in size its throwing "Out of memory!" message .. any idea how to come out of this error ...

Answer (score 0):

In case it is `.xml` put in `tar.gz` here is another implementation using `Archive::Extract`. In one-liner form

```
perl -MArchive::Extract -e "Archive::Extract->new( archive => 'src/PPM-2.50_01.tar.gz' )->extract()"
```

In source form:

```
use Archive::Extract;

Archive::Extract->new( archive => 'src/PPM-2.50_01.tar.gz' )->extract();
```

Answer (score -1):

you probably want to to a system call (backtick as it blocks until complete and gives you the result) to tar as Archive::Tar loads the whole archive into memory

something along the lines of

```
my $ret = `tar zxf $TAR_FILE_WORK_PATH`;
```

then check $ret for success.

You can use the -v (verbose) option for more output to check in $ret

Most tar commands have a -C option to extract to a specified directory which could be useful too.

Comment: The question says "using perl", which, while you have, does not encompass forking, launching a shell, and executing an external program. This goes doubly when there are multiple perl implementations of tar and gzip.

Comment: @hd1 presumably time has moved on since I answered that in 2013. Did you have a better idea?

Comment: Yes, any of the other answers.